# auto click with C++

Tags: c++

I write a simple cpp file when your left mouse button down it will click after 50 milliseconds and it works with many windows but when I click in the Tencent Gaming Buddy(an android emulator) it is not working - so how could I get the left mouse button down when I click here is my code

```
while (true)
{
    Sleep(50);
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
    {
        if (GetCursorPos(&p))
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: did u get the hwnd of the emulator?

Comment: Which OS is this targeted for? Which UI platform is this targeted for?

Comment: @UweKeim this code is using Windows API functions, so it is targeting Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetKeyState()` relies on the internal key state machine of the calling thread, and does not work without an active message loop to update that state, which this code does not have. Use `GetAsyncKeyState()` instead.

Also, `mouse_event()` is deprecated, use `SendInput()` instead